# Percent encoding and sql LIKE query

Tags: php, sql, http, percent-encoding

How do I send a `get http request` which contains sql query with `LIKE %item%` clause? I've read about percent-encoding, but don't know yet about how do I handle such a requests.

`% sign` is handled upon `percent-encoding` so it breaks sql query.

Help!

Comment: What do you mean by "`% sign` is handled upon `percent signing`"? I don't understand.

Comment: @BenLee  I meant percent-encoding.

Comment: You're sending SQL over HTTP, presumably to be executed??? Oh, you've tagged this question with `php`. My mistake, carry on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The % sign is encoded as `%25` in URLs - is that what you are asking?

For example: http://www.google.com/?q=%25

Answer (score 2):

Just send the query portion in the query string part of the GET request.  The % signs will be URL-encoded by the browser to send to the server, and PHP will urldecode them at the other end.  The real question is WHY IN GOD'S NAME WOULD YOU DO SUCH A THING?  It's terribly insecure and leaves you open to SQL injection attacks!